# Cycles - Object instancing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, geometry

I am trying to create a scene with instanced object. So far I found a way to do it like this:

```
Object *object = new Object();
object->set_geometry(myReadMesh);
object->set_tfm(myTransformation);
scene->objects.push_back(object);
```

Now comes up my problem: How do I set up different shaders per each instance? Unfortunately the shader is set on the geometry level and not on the object level.
Thanks all.

Comment: unusual question... do you really need to do that at the C++ level?